# WordPress Update E-Mail shows IP instead of Domain

Tags: domain, hosting, ip

since a couple of days I am having some issues regarding IP and Domain of my site. My server delivers 2 images from a slider and the slider CSS file via the IP of the site, not via its domain. The weird thing is that only the slider stuff gets delivered via the IP, the rest is fine.

Additionally, I got the E-Mail this morning notifying me about the update to 4.9.2, which also has the IP instead of the domain name in the E-Mail ("we upgraded your site https://123.456.... to 4.9.2").

I already checked the WP URL under Settings > General, it is as it should be. I ran a DB query searching for the IP, and there are 3 entries in the wp_options table. Could this be the problem? Other than that, it might be important that I am using WP-Rocket and a CDN for the delivery of all static files.

Cheers

--- UPDATE:
Okay, now I replaced everything in the database what started with https://THEIPOFMYSERVER with https://example.com, and I can still see the server delivering the sliders assets over the IP. There is no single entry anymore in the DB containing the IP, but the issue still persists. My best guess is that its an issue with WP-Rocket and LayerSlider.

Comment: What are `option_name`-s where IP exists?

Comment: @MaxYudin _transient_bsr_results is the only one that I can find now.

Comment: It's probably your CDN. Try turning it off and clearing all the caches - that way you can confirm it is the source of the IPs. From there, check with your particular CDN provider to see if they allow URL masking, to where it looks like the assets are coming from one of your subdomains instead of their plain IP address.

Comment: This is Better Search Replace's transient. Something happened during the site migration or similar.